# Establishing BLE pairing by passkey method

Tags: swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm able to connect to the Bluetooth device, but iOS doesn't ask for pairing with it
in result bluetooth icon keeps blinking on the connected device's screen. I found it required that passkey should be transmitted and iOS would take care of that automatically once the correct argument in place.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == self.peripheral {
            print("Connected to your Bluetooth Device")
            peripheral.discoverServices([Peripheral.bloodPressureMeasurementUUID, Peripheral.bloodPressureMeasurementUUIDSecon, Peripheral.currentTimeUUID, Peripheral.currentTimeServiceUUID])

        }
    }
```

I'm currently using these delegate methods:
`centralManagerDidUpdateState` `didDiscover` `didConnect` `didDiscoverServices` `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor`

But can't figure it out in which function `argument` I should pass that pairing should be established by a `passkey`?

Comment: You need to try to read an encrypted property, and that will trigger the pairing pop up with the code to enter.

Comment: @Larme Can you provide please an example of that for `Peripheral.currentTimeUUID` and is reading done in `didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor` delegate method?

Comment: DiscoverPeripheral -> didDiscoverPeripheral -> DiscoverService -> didDiscoverService -> ReadCharacteristic -> didReadCharacteristic, that's the logic behind BLE that use delegates. I don't you know which one of the characteristic of your BLE device is encrypted. Once you discovered characteristic, you can check its property to know that. You can also use LightBlue which will do all that, and let you know which one is encrypted.